How the operator is invertible?
I am going to solve particular solution of a differential equation $(D^2-5D+6)y=x^2$.
Here $Dy=\frac{dy}{dx}$
My book gives 
Now my question how the operator $(1-\frac{D}{3})$ and $(1-\frac{D}{2})$ is invertible?
And I have found a idea from functional analysis

where $\rho(T)$ is the spectral radius of the operator $T.$
My question :  How to find the spectral radius of $\frac{D}{2}$ and $\frac{D}{3}$.

What is $D$?.....

I'd guess $Dy=\frac{dy}{dx}$?

$C \exp(k x)$ is an eigenvector of $D$ with eigenvalue $k$ for any (real or complex) $k,C$. So over $C^1(\mathbb R)$, $D$ doesn't seem to have a finite spectral radius?

If you want the spectral radius of an operator you have to fix the domain of the operator. It seems you are working with polynomials. If $P_n$ is the vector space of polynomials  with degree $\le n$ then $D:P_n \to P_n$ is a nilpotent operator since $D^{n+1}=0$, so $\rho(D)=0$.

If we have $e^{mx}$ or $sinx$ type functions in the co-domain then ...?

For example $(D^2+4)y=sin2x$  here we have to show that $(1+\frac{D}{4i}) $ is invertible.
